# How to change Invoice increment id?

Tags: invoice, magento-2.1.8, increment-id

I want to change Invoice increment id from new series with the prefix.

I have checked sequence_invoice table in the database. I have found 4 table:

```
sales_invoice_0

sales_invoice_1

sales_invoice_2

sales_invoice_3
```

I have found entries only in sales_invoice_2 table like `1,2,3,4 and soon`. So I am confused to change invoice number.

Can anyone suggest me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> sales_invoice_0 is for default store view.
>
> sales_invoice_1 is for 1st store view.
>
> sales_invoice_2 is for 2nd store view.
>
> sales_invoice_3 is for 3rd store view.

If you change your series with the prefix you can use this,

```
ALTER TABLE sequence_invoice_1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 700000011;
```

Magento default provides 9 digits for Id. if you want to change it with prefix then replace `700000011` with your new series Id. and execute it in the database.

This will help you more.

Comment: Can I add text as prefix with the series?

Comment: If I add text as prefix (ex: 'Inv') then what will be the length of series?

Comment: Yes you can use text as prefix. Please add your prefix value in `sales_sequence_profile` tabel.

Comment: @Vinodkumar Have you tried this solution.? Is this working for you.?

Comment: Thanks, It is working fine. I have accepted your answer.

Comment: Not working if table already data.